# Usuarios y Sesiones

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy haciendo un simple sistema de control de stock, quiero darle privacidad a mis usuarios con un login, pero tengo dos dudas, ya hice el login y cree una tabla en `mysql` que se llama `usuarios`, puedo registrar usuarios y si esta registrado puede inicia sesión.

Mi  primer problema inicia en que puedo saltear el login colocando la barra de direcciones en vez de `index.php` que es el login, poner `adminStock.php` que ya entras al sistema. ¿Como puedo evitar eso?

Mi segundo problema es que puedo registrar a la cantidad de usuarios que quiera pero entran todos al mismo inventario de stock, como puedo hacer para tener distintas `sesiones` y que cada usuario acceda a su propio inventario de stock.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de las sesiones de php, esto al hacer la consulta con los datos del formulario del login.

```
session_start();
                        $_SESSION["sesion_activa"] = $usuario_bd;
                        $_SESSION["tipo_usuario"] = $tipo_usuario;
```

En este caso yo ocupo $usuario_bd; para almacenar el id del usuario, y $tipo_usuario para almacenar su tipo y así usarlo en todas mis vista del sistema y saber que permisos tiene. Esto puedes igual checar en la siguiente página https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar `session_start()` y crear las variables de session (`$_SESSION`) con las cuales verificaras que si esta definida esa variable de session lo dejaras accesar a la pagina, en tu caso es `adminStock.php`.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("Location: adminStock.php");
    }

    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
        $error = '';

        $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

        $sql = "SELECT id, id_tipo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
        $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
        $rows = $result->num_rows;

        if($rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['id_tipo'];

            header("location: adminStock.php");
            } else {
            $error = "El nombre o contraseña son incorrectos";
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" > 
            <div><label>Usuario:</label><input id="usuario" name="usuario" type="text" ></div>
            <br />
            <div><label>Password:</label><input id="password" name="password" type="password"></div>
            <br />
            <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div> 
        </form> 

        <br />

        <div style = "font-size:16px; color:#cc0000;"><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '' ; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y dentro de `adminStock.php` antes del `DOCTYPE` de html deberás verificar que exista dicha variable de session de lo contrario lo regresaras al login de usuario.

Código:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
   header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Para poder manejar diferentes `Stocks` primero que nada debes de tener una estructura en tu base de datos adecuada para poder manejar toda esa información y que dicha tabla donde manejes el stock tenga una `llave foránea` que apunte hacia el `id del usuario` para que al momento de que el usuario ingrese puedas hacer un `select` de toda la información de stock de ese usuario con una clausula `where`.